# If $G$ is abelian, it has a subgroup in every order of $|G|'s$ divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume that $G$ is an abelian group, I read somewhere that it can be derived from Lagrange's theorem that it has a number of subgroups that is equal to the number of $G$'s divisors.

Why does it hold? I'm confused...

Comment: Groups with this property are called CLT groups (converse langrange theorem). The set of CLT groups is properly contained in the set of soluble groups. The set of supersoluble groups is properly contained in the set of CLT groups. In other words, CLT implies soluble and supersoluble implies CLT. Since abelian implies supersoluble we have that abelian implies CLT.

Comment: You need to assume that $G$ is a *finite* abelian group.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thank you. Otherwise things make no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups trivializes it. We also prove it without this theorem using strong induction. The base case when the order is $n$ and $n=1$ is trivial.

Inductive step: Let $|G|=n$ and $d|n$ we need to prove there is a subgroup of order $d$. If $d=1$ we are done. Else let $p$ be a prime dividing $d$. By Cauchy's theorem there is a subgroup $P$ of $G$ of order $p$. Since $G$ is abelian, $P$ is normal. Hence we can consider the homomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow \frac{G}{P}$. The group $\frac{G}{P}$ has order $\frac{n}{p}$. By the inductive hypothesis there is a subgroup $C$ of $\frac{G}{P}$ of order $\frac{d}{p}$.

Apply the first isomorphism theorem:

$\frac{\varphi^{-1}(C)}{P}\cong C$. This tells us $|\varphi^{-1}(C)|=|P||\frac{G}{P}|=p\frac{d}{p}=d$. So $\varphi^{-1}(C)$ is the group we were looking for.

Comment: Alternatively, $\varphi^{-1}(C)/P = C$ can be seen with the correspondence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you mean is that if $G$ is a finite abelian group of order $n$, then $G$ has at least one subgroup of order $d$ for every divisor $d\ge 1$ of $n$. This claim follows easily from the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups. Note that it does not state that there is a unique subgroup of every divisor. In fact, a finite group $G$ is cyclic if, and only if, it has at most one subgroup of every possible divisor. In any case, the general theorem does not state how many subgroups of a particular order there are. Only that there is at least one of every possible divisor.

Obviously, there is precisely one subgroup of order $1$ and precisely one subgroup of order $n$. Each of the cyclic groups $\mathbb Z_n$ has precisely one subgroup of every possible order. The Klein group $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ has three subgroups of order $2$.